# Is it possible to have a DatePicker as a navigationBarItem in an iPad app?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, ipados

I'm trying to simply add a DatePicker in SwiftUI to a navigation bar, this is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                leading: DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on iOS but on the iPad simulator when I click the date picker nothing happens and the console prints some layout constraint error and this:

> UIDatePicker 0x7fc3511141d0 is being laid out below its minimum width
> of 280. This may not look like expected, especially with larger than
> normal font sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the *leading* position in the navigation bar is occupied by the sidebar button. As an alternative to `.navigationBarItems`, you can use `toolbar` and specify a `placement`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I used the `.principal` placement because it seems there's no enough space to render a `DatePicker` as `.navigationBarLeading`. However, feel free to try other placements.*